# Problem with simple full-text search on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I just setup full-text search on my development database. I setup a new full-text index on a table and included 2 columns in the index. The first column is called 'description' and is a 'varchar(100)' and the other column is called 'notes' and is a 'text' column.

I am trying to perform a simple search like this:

```
select *
from myTable
where freetext(description, 'another')
```

I know for sure that there is at least one row where the 'description' column contains the word 'another' as the first word. However, the search produces 0 results. Searching for other words seems to work fine.

Also, when I setup my full-text index I told it to automatically update the index and to go ahead and build the index right away. The database hasn't changed at all since I did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server considers 'another' to be a stopword (noise word).  So for all intents and purposes, it is ignored when performing a `FULLTEXT` search.

See `C:\WINDOWS\system32\noise.eng` (that is where it is installed on my system) for a full list of noise/stop words.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That raises another question though, what happens when a stop word is contained in a phrase search?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is handled, actually.